# How do you escape the trademark or copyright symbol in markdown?

Tags: markdown

With markdown I want to say something like:

```
The parser consumes a .tm file.
```

But (in my GitHub readme.md markdown file) and also using Markdown Pro on my mac, markdown wants to make the tm a superscripted TM trademark symbol.  I've tried backslashes in various locations .\tm, .\t\m, .(tm), etc.  but I just end up with the slashes in the output text.  Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

As I type this I can see that stackoverflow is using markdown and I'm not getting that behavior!  Whuuhh?  Insight appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.  Turns out it's got nothing to do with markdown.  Mac OS X has a text replacement feature that makes the TM symbol automatically.  Edit->Substitutions->Text Replacement

Answer (score 10):

For anyone arriving here wondering how to make a TM (trademark) symbol in their github flavored markdown (or github README.me), it's as simple as:

```
:tm:
```

[image]

I found it from [this comprehensive list](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908)

Comment: Agreed, this is not the most specific answer to OP's question, but it is a concise and complete answer to the question I had when I googled it and clicked on the first SO hit.  I understand SO wants to cultivate its specific and responsive Q&A policy, and I'd prefer to see that dominate, but in the meantime, good answers to my own questions that google shows me on SO are worth a boost.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout backticks?

```
The parser consumes a `.tm` file.
```

Comment: Just tried it in my markdown editor and I got this:  .&trade;

Comment: Really? https://github.com/mjball/glowing-hipster/blob/master/README.md Even without the backticks, the GitHub readme does not do any substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html in Markdown:

- Trademark: `&trade;`
- Copyright: `&copy;`

The Markdown-specific versions are:

- Trademark: `:tm:`
- Copyright: `:copyright:`

If you use Typora editor, you can type `:` and start typing what you think the shortcut name might be and it gives you a dropdown list of options.